# Using wireshark along with ns3

Tags: wireshark

I am searching google to learn how to use wireshark along with ns-3, but I am confused. As I see it needs specific file to work. How do I make this specific file with ns-3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is still unclear. I assume you need the following lines of code.

```
PointToPointHelper p2p;
p2p.EnablePcapAll("filename"); //filename without .pcap extention
```

It will create a file in the main directory of ns3. You can analyze this file using tcpdump or wireshark.